# python pandas drop value from column 'B' if that value appears in column 'A'

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

This code appears to drop duplicates from 'A', but leaves 'B' untouched:

```
df1.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
```

Edit: That actually drops nothing... What's going on here?

Code (boiled down):

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,0,8,3,4,5,3,3,3,9,9],
                        'B':[5,5,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
print(df1)
df1.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
    A  B
0   1  5
1   4  5
2   0  7
3   8  4
4   3  2
5   4  0
6   5  0
7   3  0
8   3  0
9   3  0
10  9  0
11  9  0

[12 rows x 2 columns]
    A  B
0   1  5
1   4  5
2   0  7
3   8  4
4   3  2
5   4  0
6   5  0
7   3  0
10  9  0
[9 rows x 2 columns]
```

I think I see what's happening above since it was these asterisked rows dropped:

```
7   3  0
8   3  0*
9   3  0*
10  9  0
11  9  0*
```

But I still can't see how to remove duplicates in 'B' (or return unique values in 'B'). The two columns are actually coming from separate CSV files. Should I not join them into a single DataFrame? Is there are way to compare and drop duplicates if I don't?

Edit:
This is the output I'm looking for (asterisked values deleted, or plus-marked values to be returned):

```
    A  B
0   1  5*
1   4* 5*
2   0* 7+
3   8  4*
4   3* 2+
5   4* 0*
6   5* 0*
7   3* 0*
10  9  0*
[9 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually have duplicates?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? Help us to help you by giving us the detail necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: I have an existing list from 'GridExport.csv' and list of new records from 'new.csv'. I want to get the unique records from 'new.csv'.

Comment: If you can cut it down to a minimum failing test case, we can probably figure out what it is.  (Equally likely, you'll figure out the problem while doing so.)

Comment: Curious as to why you changed `Record` into type `float` on line 9 ?

Comment: To handle bad data that wouldn't fit into type int. I've removed all that fluff in the edit.

Comment: What do you expect as an output from your example ?

Comment: I was expecting duplicates between the columns to be dropped. I would have expected the first instance of a duplicate to survive in column 'A', but all of them to be dropped in 'B' (keep first). There will of course be unique values in 'A', but I don't need to keep those unique values, and would want to keep them separate from the unique values in 'B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,0,8,3,4,5,3,3,3,9,9],
                        'B':[5,5,7,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
print(df1)
cln = df1.unstack().drop_duplicates()
cln.drop(['A'], inplace=True)
print(cln)
cln = cln.reset_index(drop=True)
print(cln)
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
    A  B
0   1  5
1   4  5
2   0  7
3   8  4
4   3  2
5   4  0
6   5  0
7   3  0
8   3  0
9   3  0
10  9  0
11  9  0

[12 rows x 2 columns]
B  2    7
   4    2
dtype: int64
0    7
1    2
dtype: int64
```